# JavaScript Loop not recognising global variable

Tags: javascript

I am following a javascript book and trying to re-implement the books code examples in my own way.

i keep getting "ReferenceError: test is not defined" in the Firefox debugger

Thisis my code :

```
      <script>

        var test1 = "abcdef";
        var test2 = 123;
        var test3 = true;
        var test4 = {};
        var test5 = [];
        var test6;
        var test7 = { "abcdef": 123 };
        var test8 = ["abcdef", 123];
        function test9() { return "abcdef" };

        for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {

            var probe = test[i];
            alert((typeof probe).toString);

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: `test` isn't defined. None of your variables have that name.

Comment: ... and `.toString` is a property. You'll likely want to call it as a function (or omit it altogether).

Comment: `typeof` returns a string, why convert it to string again?

Answer (score 2):

`test[1]`  is not at all the same as `test1`.  What you want is

```
    var test = [];
    test[1] = "abcdef";
    test[2] = 123;
    test[3] = true;
    test[4] = {};
    test[5] = [];
    test[6];
    test[7] = { "abcdef": 123 };
    test[8] = ["abcdef", 123];
    test[9] = function() { return "abcdef" };

    for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {

        var probe = test[i];
        alert(typeof probe);

    }
```

Comment: Agreed, this is *probably* what the OP wants. [Here it is as a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T8gYC/)

Answer (score 1):

When you write test[i], you approached the array named 'test', at the i index, which causes an error of course, since the test array does not exists.
In order to implement your code correctly, you can either write:

```
var test = [];
test[1] = "abcdef"; 
test[2] = 123;
```

and so on.

This is fine too:

```
var obj ={};
obj.test1 = "abcdef";
obj.test2= 123;
```

And in your loop use:

```
var probe = obj["test"+i];
```

(Your loop index should be initialized with 1 and not with 0)

Answer (score 0):

`test` is not really defined.
so just change the `test` to some other variable name which you have declared already.

```
        var test1 = "abcdef";
        var test2 = 123;
        var test3 = true;
        var test4 = {};
        var test5 = [];
        var test7 = { "abcdef": 123 };
        var test8 = ["abcdef", 123];
```